# Older flags still "waiting for review" while newer ones were recently "approved", why?

Tags: support

So far, at the time of this question, I have the following stats for my flags:

[image: Flag Stats]

Some of my recently flags that were marked as *helpful* were reported and accepted yesterday on the same day. Yet, I still have flags back from July 11th (over a month ago) still *waiting for review*.

Why makes my old flags still being held in queue while some recently flags that I've use get accepted much sooner?

As you can see I have 1 *aged away* flag since it was reported awhile ago. Just want to know what determines the priority.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flags get approved in two ways: by sufficient ordinary reviewers or people with close review rights. So if there are plenty of people with ordinary review rights active on a day, you may see your flags approved immediately, simply because enough flags are raised on that particular question.

Once your flagged post slides down the list it becomes less likely that enough ordinary reviewers flag for automatic deletion. It then depends on people with close review rights. There are less of them and your flag may end up in the queue so long that the system decides it's no longer worth it keeping it there.

Comment: I see, so the _Close Votes_ section in the Review page is where the reported flags go. Similar to reviewing a _First Post / Late Answer_, the most recent ones show up on the top? Right now, I see **124** flags needing review. Is reviewing a flag a bigger task?

Comment: I don't think it is a bigger task (160 more rep and I'll find out for sure), but there are less people doing it and you still need three votes to finally close a question...

Comment: So the older flags that I've made most likely have only 1-2 votes so they won't show up on the queue then

Comment: @cjbj You actually need _5 close votes_ to finally close a question.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Which explains even more why we need more 3000+ people active.

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan I reached 3000+ (yay!) and found out that the close vote queue is random. Every time I reload the page I get another question to review.

Comment: @cjbj Great, thanks for the update. I noticed last night when you had 40 rep to go, so I thought I'd help upvote some of your best answers to get you up to 3k. Like McGee said, _we need more 3k+ rep people active_. It looks like this is to ensure some older votes don't stay at the bottom of the queue?

Comment: @cjbj I also noticed the queue has dropped (~20 votes right now) since you've  gotten the privilege. Glad to see it's being worked on.

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan Thanks for the upvotes. I'm currently rationed to 25 close votes a day, but that will go up the coming days, I suppose.

Answer (score 7):

Flags that are pseudo close votes [go to the close vote review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169578/combine-close-votes-review-queue-with-flags-to-close), not to the moderator desk. And there they stay, until someone resolves the post in question.

Here are the flags that will go straight to the normal review queue:

[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit _which_ flags would those be? For example I don't remember on top of my head. :)

Comment: @Rarst Done, see the update.